# Release version throws IOException when saving to bin file

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm having a problem with C#. About a week ago I made an application in C# which consists on a Datagrid which shows data from a bin file, allowing people to edit it with the DataGrid and in the Window_Closing event, a method runs which saves it all back in the bin.

The thing is that it was working fine until I recompiled a version (I was asked later to make the DataGrid read-only, but I still need to save to the .bin because of other info) and I didnt touch neither the method for saving and nothing related to it. Then someone told me that it crashed when they closed it and I checked and it was an IOException when it tries to write on the file (which worked perfectly until I changed the dataGrid thing) but writes perfectly if I change the name (I used try/catch), I don't know what other information I should post here so if you need anything to help me just ask

```
public void guardar()
{
    try
    {
        File.Delete("Save.bin");
        Save S = new Save(listaProyectos, @"\\192.168.1.250\proyectos");
        FileStream F = new FileStream("Save.bin", FileMode.Create);
        BinaryFormatter b = new BinaryFormatter();
        b.Serialize(F, S);
        F.Close();
    }
    catch (IOException)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        Save S = new Save(listaProyectos, @"\\192.168.1.250\proyectos");
        FileStream F = new FileStream(r.Next(0,999).ToString()+".bin", FileMode.Create);
        BinaryFormatter b = new BinaryFormatter();
        b.Serialize(F, S);
        F.Close();
    }
}
```

the catch section doesnt crash for some reason, even though im just giving it a random name

EDIT: Because someone asked me, I think (but im not sure because the debugger is not working correctly with this bug) that the line it crashes is in `FileStream F = new FileStream("Save.bin", FileMode.Create);`

EDIT2: Because of time issues, I had to remake a huge amount of the project and now it doesn't crash (But it's pretty much a whole new program that works in a different way, so the problem wasn't "solved"), but I'll leave the question open and try the different solutions you propose for anyone who may be having a similar problem.

EDIT3: The stacktrace with MessageBox.Show(ex) throwed me that the file is in use in the `FileStream F = new FileStream("Save.bin", FileMode.Create);` line.

Comment: `File.Delete` will throw a `IOException` if the file is in use, or otherwise has an open file handle on it.  The fact that it works if you change the name reinforces this theory.

Comment: It may be helpful for others to suggest fixes, if You post which line exactly causes the exception in Your scenario.

Comment: You haven't mentioned which line throws the `IOException`. The `FileStream` constructor can also throw an `IOException`. Given the file is being created on a shared folder, is it possible another user has already created the same file? Which would explain why renaming works.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, I cant make out which line throws the exception because the debugger isnt showing me which one but only based on "Try-catch" tests I figured out its the FileStream F = new Filestream(...)

Comment: You don't need the debugger - just add a "Console.WriteLine(ex)" in your catch block (or a message box equivalent) and post the stacktrace here (also make sure that the "Project Settings/Build/Advanced Build Settings" have at least "pdb-only" set for "Debug Info" for the "Release" build configuration).

Comment: Exceptions contain a stack-trace and often a message with some details. It's useful to log that information, so you're better equipped to solve crashes like this. Also note that `FileStream` is disposable, but you're not disposing it. The `Close` call should take care of that too, but always disposing disposables is a good habit to adopt. As for `IOException`s, there are various possible causes for that: files that are in use, folders that don't exist or are not accessible, lack of required permissions...

Comment: I answered what the stack-trace said in an Edit (it was in spanish), later today the co-worker who manages the network drive in which is trying to save is coming to the office and I'll ask him if he's having a problem with the drive recently or if there are permission issues